# Implement Jersey (JAX-RS) client library for php REST webservices on server

Tags: android, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have php webservices available on web server, I am trying to develop an Android project which will consume responses of those.

Jersey (JAX-RS) provides a client library to communicate with RESTful webservices, which can be used in my android app (client).

So I have some questions:

- Does Jersey (JAX-RS) works with php webservices on server, or it needs Jersey web-services on server
- If yes, Is it good idea to do it with Jersey
- What are the other options which I have, to consume my php web services in android app

Comment: hi, i think yes you can..but why Jersey? you can use framework Volley for consume..

Comment: thnaks for the suggestion! Does it provide all the implementation support? I am looking into it,. need to study a bit about it..never worked on volley.

Comment: i post more details in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can consume your PHP web services in Android.

I advise to use Volley Framework (Google);[Volley Framework](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

And here you can check many example:

[Example Volley Frameworks](https://github.com/balduzzi85/android_volley_examples)

Comment: thanks..what could be potential drawbacks in using Jersey JAX-RS, or may be you could mention what could be benefits of using Volley over Jersey JAX-RS. **could anyone else please explain it**, if possible. _(no offense! it might be personal choice of Antonio)_

Answer (score 0):

I have made some understanding about the topic since I asked about it, and here are some info If someone comes searching for the same thing later.

No need to learn a new thing: Jersey JAX-RS to consume the web services into an android app. (If you are not already into it.)

So to consume the web services into an android app, we have following options:

- HttpURLConnection or Apache HTTP Client: [Google has deprecated Apache HTTP client usage since Gingerbread.](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) So you may use HttpURLConnection to request response to your web services.
- [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/): This is also a good library to consume REST responses into android app.
- Volley: Google has created a library claiming it very faster.

> library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most
> importantly, faster.

And it follows [RPC-style networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) operations, also have interface so you can spend more time implementing your logic.

PS: Thanks Antonio for your suggestion.